# Kubernetes - unable to access my external service

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, service

This is my template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi
  labels:
    app: fastapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi
          image: datamastery/fastapi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30002
```

I use a custom fastapi Docker image, which works fine locally. If I understand it correctly, I can expose my Service to the outside world on port 30002.

I run `minikube service fastapi-service` and a new Browsertab opens with the following URL: `http://192.168.49.2:30002`. Unfortunately nothing is shown. I tried the internal URL (`http://127.0.0.1:55202`) which also does not work, as expected. Am I doing here something wrong with Kubernetes or might my app be the issue? Does anyone see something I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the my sandbox logs, it seems like its listening on port `3000`

```
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:3000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

so change the port from `5000` to `3000`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi
  labels:
    app: fastapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi
          image: datamastery/fastapi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30002
```

[image]